# gradient border with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set border color for a round div with javascript. User picks two colors (red and blue, for example) and the border becomes red on top and blue on bottom. But from the sides the border should change from red to blue, vice versa. In other words, I need to make vertical gradient for div's borders.
I can make it with just css, but since I don't know which colors would be chosen, I need javascript to do that for me.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

A pure-javascript solution to do just that. Note that you need to do a funky getCssValuePrefix to determine which browser, thus calling the appropriate linear-gradient function.

```js
var clicky = document.getElementById("changeButton"),
    color1 = document.getElementById("color1"),
    color2 = document.getElementById("color2"),
    changeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0];

clicky.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (color1.value && color2.value) {
  var myGradientString = getCssValuePrefix()+"linear-gradient("+color1.value+", "+color2.value+")";
  
  changeDiv.style.background = myGradientString;
  }
});

function getCssValuePrefix()
{
    var rtrnVal = '';//default to standard syntax
    var prefixes = ['-o-', '-ms-', '-moz-', '-webkit-'];

    // Create a temporary DOM object for testing
    var dom = document.createElement('div');

    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++)
    {
        // Attempt to set the style
        dom.style.background = prefixes[i] + 'linear-gradient(#000000, #ffffff)';

        // Detect if the style was successfully set
        if (dom.style.background)
        {
            rtrnVal = prefixes[i];
        }
    }

    dom = null;
    delete dom;

    return rtrnVal;
}
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</p>
</div>
<label for="color1">Color 1: <input type="text" name="color1" id="color1" value="#ee3"></label>
<label for="color2">Color 2: <input type="text" name="color2" id="color2" value="#336"></label>
<button id="changeButton">Make it so!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution working exactly how you want :) I have tasted that on Chrome, MF and Opera. Paste my demo to empty html file. Good luck!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
    #test
      {
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          border-width: 3px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-image:
            linear-gradient(blue, red) 1;

    }

    </style>

    <body>
     <input id="first" type="text">
     <input id="second" type="text">
     <input type="submit" onclick="changeColor()">

     <div id="test"> </div>

<script>

      var one = document.getElementById("first");
      var two = document.getElementById("second");
      var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");

 function changeColor()
          {
           testDiv.style.borderImage = "linear-gradient(" + one.value + ", " + two.value + ") 1 ";
           }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```